# Declaring a variadic function in C99 without other parameters

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I am trying to implement low-level code that passes variadic arguments to a function pointer (with the function defined in NASM). This pointer can change at any time, so I need to declare a function pointer with the following signature:

```
typedef int (__fastcall* callback)(...);
```

However, unless I declare it with a non-variadic parameter (which wont work), the compiler outputs the error "error : expected a type specifier". Is there any way to fix this just using C? Is there a different implementation that would work short of adjusting all of the other parameters based on calling convention in assembly? Any ideas or solutions would be appreciated.

Edit: I'm aware that this is a very hacky implementation, but I am working with a legacy codebase. So as much as I'd like to, I can't completely change how everything works as I need a solution which will work in the current codebase.

Comment: A function with variadic parameters must have at least one ordinary parameter. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Omit parameter information `typedef int (__fastcall* callback)();`

Comment: Post some sample uses would provide insight.

Comment: @chux: This is not standard compliant since C99 and does not mean yyou can pass any type of arguments.

Comment: Looks like XY problem. Without at least one argument specifying the number (and possibly type) of arguments, how will your function determine types and/or number of arguments?

Comment: @Olaf A variable that will allow the function to identify the number of variables is stored separately. I don't need to pass the number of variables to it.

Comment: @Olaf "how will your function determine types and/or number of arguments? " --> Pre-standard C89 allowed `foo(...)`.  The usual method to determine type/number count was based on a global.  Another use was a bit-bucket - parameters were not determined.  `foo(...)` had limited uses.

Comment: @chux: That's what I'm doing - storing the number of arguments and other information in global data and registers. If there's no way to do this within C99 (at least in a standard-compliant way), will any issues arise out of declaring it with no arguments rather than variable arguments? So long as the caller handles calling convention correctly, the callee will not have issues.

Comment: Can the functions pass a dummy first argument?  It would be more complaint than declaring it with no arguments.

Comment: @chux: That's really the main issue. I'm entirely relying on the arguments being passed in the proper order based on calling convention. While this isn't an issue on 32-bit with __cdecl, there's no way I can just 'pop' a dummy argument with __fastcall.

Comment: @frank90: Can you make the first arg a real arg that always has the same type?  Or at least, one that will always fit in a register?  e.g. declare it as `void*`, and pass whatever you want?  Maybe put a macro around actual calls, to cast the first parameter to a compatible type.  (So integer types as the first arg get cast to `void*`, which is ugly, but the right data is there when your asm function runs.)

Comment: @chux: There's a reason this is not allowed in standard C. And using globals as OP commented is just a very bad idea. We don't code in the 60/70ies (or 80ies BASIC) anymore. There is a clear advice: **do not**!

Comment: `__cdecl` and `__fastcall` are not standard C. Either way, you are on the wrong track. Do yourself a favour and rethink your design.

Comment: @Olaf your  comment asked "how will your function determine ...".  As `foo(...)` was allowed in C at one time, my comment answer how it was done.  As to if it is a good idea or not is not the issue.  You ask how, I answered and am not judgmental if it is a good idea.

Comment: @chux: Maybe I should have tagged as rethorical question. And yes, it very well correct to question the approach OP uses in his question. IIRC, one reason for SO is to improve the quiality of program code.

Comment: @Olaf I tried `typedef int (* callback)(); callback foo = strcmp;` with `gcc -std=c11 -O0 -g -pedantic -Wall -Wextra`.  How is this not " standard compliant since C99"?

Comment: @chux: Hmm, it should warn about using non-prototype style function declarator. Maybe it's the pointer type definition. Anyway, that is not the right type, as using var_arg requires using the ellipsis.

Comment: @Olaf. OK Tried `typedef int (* callback)(); int bar(); callback foo = bar;`.  Still no warnings/errors.  AKAIK, C99 does not require the parameter of a function that is a function pointer, to have that function pointer to have its parameter signature completely spelled out.  This apparently contradicts [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35257244/declaring-a-variadic-function-in-c99-without-other-parameters?noredirect=1#comment58226998_35257244) and "works" in this answer's code snippet.

Comment: @chux: Hmm, I seem to have been a bit too foreseeing: Omitting `void` is an obsolescence feature (see 6.11.6/7). But still, as OP wants to call with different argument numbers (and possibly other types that `int`), it violates 6.5.2.2p2 . Anyway, we both seem to agree this is a bad idea in general. No need to exactly track down where it violates the standard exactly.

Comment: @chux : Pre-89 standard C didn't DO ANY type checking of arguments, shorts were promoted to ints, floats to doubles, the caller just pushed them onto the stack, the callee referenced them and it was up to the programmer to have the order & types of paramaters right.

Comment: If you have to call the legacy assembler function from C99 code, can't you write an interface layer function in assembler to handle the impedance mismatch?    Otherwise I dont' see why C needs to know anything about the assembly parameters at all, a function pointer is simply a pointer value

Comment: @chux The declaration `foo(...)` was never allowed. Before C89 `...` wasn't even a valid token. In C (but not C++) you can indeed use `foo()` to mean an unspecified, maybe variable, list of arguments. It's not clear though that this solution wouldn't just be masking the real problem with the code.

Comment: It not clear whether you have multiple different assembly functions that are being called from C code through this pointer, or if you have multiple different C functions that are called through the pointer from assembly. It's also not clear if this function pointer needs to be variadic because the function signature changes when the pointer changes or because the individual functions being called are variadic. Finally what do you mean by "storing the number of arguments .. in ... registers"? You can't do this and follow a calling convention without passing it as an argument.

Comment: @RossRidge I'm talking about multiple different assembly functions that are being called from C code through this pointer. The function signature also never changes. As far as storing the number of arguments "in registers", I'm not doing it within the same thread or relying on calling convention as far as that goes... I'd really rather not get into explaining the entire mess.